# C# Efficent way to get color at point on screen

Tags: c#, .net, colors, screen

I do have a working method however it is fairly resource intensive and I am looking for a better way. Running the code below was suggested on a response to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483928/how-to-read-the-color-of-a-screen-pixel/1483963#1483963).

However running said code yields a `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

The exception happens @ `using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(screenPixel)) {`

Current code:

```
Bitmap screenPixel = new Bitmap(1, 1, PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555);
using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(screenPixel)) {
    using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)) {
        IntPtr hSrcDC = gsrc.GetHdc();
        IntPtr hDC = gdest.GetHdc();
        int retval = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, 1, 1, hSrcDC, x, y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        gdest.ReleaseHdc();
        gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
        }
   }
    return screenPixel.GetPixel(0, 0);
```

EDIT:

Okay so I've fixed the issue I was having above with the following code. However now I am only getting the color black (0,0,0) returned.

```
this.screenPixel = new Bitmap(1, 1, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);
using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(this.screenPixel)) {
    using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)) {
        IntPtr hSrcDC = gsrc.GetHdc();
        IntPtr hDC = gdest.GetHdc();
        int retval = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, width, height, hSrcDC, x, y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        gdest.ReleaseHdc();
        gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
        }
}
Color result = screenPixel.GetPixel(0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(result.R + " " + result.G + " " + result.B);
GC.SuppressFinalize(this.screenPixel);
this.screenPixel.Dispose();
return result;
```

Comment: Why do you use `Format16bppArgb1555`? which line throws the exception?

Comment: I have tried with and without, I only have it because I only need 8 bit color precision. I'll update the post as to which line throws the exception.

Comment: Is `screenPixel` a class member or a local variable?  In the linked solution it is a class member that is reused (and hopefully disposed of in the Dispose method of the form).

Comment: BTW: `using` already calls `Dispose`, why do you explicitly call it. Try by removing them....

Comment: I've already removed it.

Comment: Also @dbc it is a class member.

Comment: I would use the format your screen is displaying or default. -  which line throws the exception???

Comment: Does it throw an exception when you use PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb?

Comment: You have to acutally dispose these objects, they take handles on system resources.

Comment: @asawyer What objects are you referring to?

Comment: Just look for EyeDropper Examples in .NET and alter it to fit your needs: http://bobpowell.net/eyedropper.aspx

Comment: @walshie4 The GDI+ objects hold references to windows resources that must be disposed.

Comment: @asawyer I'm releasing them. Which variable in particular are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work here:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//... 


[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern int BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest, 
   int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjSource, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int  dwRop);

//..

    Bitmap screenPixel = new Bitmap(1, 1, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
    using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(screenPixel))
    {
        using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            IntPtr hSrcDC = gsrc.GetHdc();
            IntPtr hDC = gdest.GetHdc();
            int retval = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, 1, 1, hSrcDC, x, y,
                                    (int) CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            gdest.ReleaseHdc();
            gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
        }
    }
    Color c =  screenPixel.GetPixel(0, 0);
    return c;
```

Note 1:

- I have changed the pixel format to match my screen.
- I have fiddled with the BitBlt declaration

Note 2:

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140375/using-bitblt-to-capture-screenshot-how) you might as well use Graphics.CopyFromScreen directly as it will use BitBlt anyway. This would be safer and less trouble imo.

Comment: Can you tell me where the `(int)0x00CC0020` value comes from?

Comment: [Here on pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32.bitblt) is a description of bitBlt and the `enum TernaryRasterOperations`. Since I thought it was missing I copied the value for `SRCCOPY`. Silly me! Note that you may want to use `int bpp = Screen.PrimaryScreen.BitsPerPixel;` to determine the color depth of your screen.